# How to say that foods with too strong taste can kill the flavor of the wine?

Tags: expressions

Recently I had a dinner with my friends and I wanted to say that, "The food's taste is so strong that it kills the flavor of the wine."

Are there expressions with the similar meaning but also with the different flavors for description? (i.e. The strong taste of the food can cover the taste ...)

Comment: The bold flavors of the food overwhelm the subtleties in the wine. Or the subtle nuances in the wine are lost to the overwhelming flavors in the food.

Comment: Alternatively, whoever paired this wine to this dish was an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a few ideas from sites discussing wine with Indian curry.

**Ruin**.

> So why **ruin** a good curry, or a good bottle of wine by putting it with the wrong partner? — http://favouritewines.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/angelas-5-tips-for-wine-and-curry.html?m=1

**Overpower**

> Indian is a tough cuisine to match any wine up against because it can be quite intense and **overpower** the wine, or make the wine taste **stringent**.  — https://winewankers.com/2014/07/03/its-riesling-with-indian/

**Clash**, **detract**, **dumb down the flavours**.

> Beer is refreshing, and it does not **clash** with the many feisty, fiery flavors of chilies, herbs, spices and sauces [...] Heavy oak dominates and can really **dumb down the flavors** — 
>   http://www.thekitchn.com/pairing-wine-with-spicy-foods-189439

Comment: @V0ight I just landed on their website randomly but think I'll remember its URL. Their strap line is funny too "G’day, you’re at the best wine blog ever! We're all about wine; without the wankery "

Comment: I add 'overshadow' here :D

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't paying attention and added enough cinnamon to ***overpower*** the taste of the apples in the recipe.

The amount of cilantro in the salad ***overwhelmed*** the subtle taste of the virgin olive oil.

The two examples I used are from experience, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You could say the food's aftertaste **soured** the wine.

[The Beautiful Game](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hg3EOVbUfBcC&pg=PA99&dq=%22soured+the+wine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjomqjm74rOAhXD7oMKHYy3AxEQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22soured%20the%20wine%22&f=false)

[image]